# Overwrite the title for a particular taxonomy page

Tags: 7, views, uri

Can anyone help me on how to overwrite the particular taxonomy page title in Drupal 7?

Let us say I have 4 or more taxonomy page. I need the page title to for 3 pages and not for 1 page. If my url is http://localhost/drupal/companies/* the title should be overwritten as "Hello"; if the url is http://localhost/drupal/technology/* the default page title should  appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easily done with the [Taxonomy Title](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_title) module.
It adds a "Term page heading" field for terms. Simply edit your term and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The [TVI](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) module lets you pick a view for each term. Then in the view you can decide to show a title or not.